# CakePHP seems to ignore foreign key

Tags: php, cakephp

I have three tables that I'm trying to query. Right now CakePHP is only pulling data from Visits and Guests, it's incorrectly joining Rooms as I'll explian.

```
Visits
id   |  guest_id   |   room_id   |   arrival_date

Guests
id    |    name   |  user_id

Rooms
id    |    user_id   |  description
```

I'm trying to get info on all three things when querying for a visit

```
$visits = $this->paginate('Visit', array(
            'arrival_date >=' => $date,
            'room.user_id' => $user_id
            )
        );
```

Here are the relationships I have in my models

Visit model

```
public $hasOne = array(
    'Guest' => array(
        'foreignKey' => 'id'
    ),
    'Room' => array(
        'foreignKey' => 'id'
    )
);
```

Room model

```
public $belongsTo = array(   //user creates a room
    'User' => array(
        'className' => 'User',
        'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => ''
    )
);

public $hasMany = array(
    'Visit' => array(
        'foreignKey' => 'visit_id',
    ),
);
```

**On every single query when I use a sql_dump it shows the join of Rooms as**

```
LEFT JOIN `TestReservations`.`rooms` AS `Room` ON (`Room`.`id` = `Visit`.`id`)
```

**It should be Room.id = Visit.room_id**

I accidentally changed the hasOne relation in my room model to room_id and I noticed it joined as "Room.room_id = visit.id". This foreign key is clearly being set through this, so why isn't the one in the visit model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your tables are setup incorrectly for that kind of relationship, respectively your relationship configuration is incorrect for your database schema.

In a has-one relationship, the *other* table contains the foreign key, ie the `guests` and `rooms` tables would need a `visit_id` column for this to work (though I don't think this is what you want, you should probably go for a differnt relationship instead).

See http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#hasone

> **foreignKey**: the name of the foreign key found in the other model. This is especially handy if you need to define multiple hasOne relationships. The default value for this key is the underscored, singular name of the current model, suffixed with ‘_id’. In the example above it would default to ‘user_id’.

Likewise with your `Room` model, in a has-many relationship the other model contains the foreign key too, ie in the configuration the foreign key should be `room_id` instead of `visit_id` (`visit_id` doesn't even exist according to your schema).

Your database schema currently reflects the following relationships:

- `Visit belongsTo Guest, Room`
- `Guest hasMany Visit`
- `Room hasMany Visit`
- `Guest belongsTo User`
- `Room belongsTo User`
- `User hasMany Guest, Room`

I don't know about the specific needs of your application, so I can't really make further suggestions for your schema (that would be something for a new question), but generally I'd say your schema looks OK *so far*. Changing it so that `Visit` would have `hasOne` relations to `Room` and `Guest` is something I'd definitely discourage, a visit is something specific to a guest and a room, but it's not exclusive, so it's correct that the `visits` table holds the foreign keys, the other way around it would be just plain wrong because a room and a guest could then only be associated with a single visit. So having that in mind, leave your tables as they are, and change to the reflected relationships for your CakePHP models as listed above.

Note that you don't have to explicitly define the foreign key in the relationship configuration, when following the CakePHP conventions for your database schema, the correct key based on the model name is generated automatically.

Comment: Thanks for the help, sorry for the delayed response. I unexpectedly had to run out of town for the night. Would you suggest re-creating the tables or is this OK? I want to become better at sticking to "proper ways" of tackling problems, so I'd really appreciate your input. Thanks again